# CSS changes not reflecting on site

Tags: asp.net, css

Whenever we make changes to the CSS, it generally takes 24 hours to reflect those changes on my site. I have tried clearing the server cache and browser cache but it doesn't help too. Is there any other way to make the CSS changes reflect immediately after updation?

it happens in all the browsers... when i check it in the browser , i can access my css file with two paths eg : i store my css in folder named "Cssfolder" and my css name is say 135.css
So when i access the folder paths, **C**ssfolder/135.css & **c**ssfolder/135.css, one of the path shows me latest css whereas other one shows me old css.Notice the "c" is captital in one path whereas small in other path.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a proxy or are the ISP caching the pages?

Comment: Is that true even if you hit Shift-F5 when viewing the "old" CSS?

Comment: yes , its true for f5 & refresh too :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found this to be a pretty common problem in a lot of my projects. I would suggest two things...

1. If it's just an app that you are working on you can use the [CSS Cachebuster](http://www.jasongraphix.com/archive/2007/08/css_cachebuster) during development.
2. Following the idea behind the Cachebuster I have found that often adding the timestamp of the CSS file as a query string off of the CSS link will help in telling the browser that the file is different... something like... whatever.css?12212009035543

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use a monitoring tool, like [Live Http Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org) for Firefox, to see the requests and responses to and from the server. This usually solves a lot of problems for me. Take a look at the "*Expire*" headers and conditional requests (like: "If-modified-since"). This said, take a look at server and client local times and timezones - it might be that they differ significantly and conditional GET requests "seem to be" handled correctly, because of future or otherwise mangled timestamps.

You can force to load the current css directly from the server with appending a random unique value to the url, like http://example.com/Cssfolder/135.css?983274928374 and http://example.com/cssfolder/134.css?08973249827. There's no way that this would ever get cached unless you use the same random value twice.

This way you learn where to look further for the solution to your problem: At the server, the ISP/a proxy or your browser.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to see whether this is server side or client side. If the server is still *serving* the old CSS then clearly you've got no chance on the client side.

I've occasionally seen times where I've had to show the CSS in the browser, and then next time I've been to the real page, it's used that new CSS. Usually just hitting refresh does it.

Do you have any web caches like Akamai involved anywhere?

If you try to go to the CSS page from a computer which has never seen the old version, which version does it show?

EDIT: Changed answer to reflect edits in question.

Comment: in this case it will show newer version, but servers cannot change so everytime i update the code on server i face this issue. and i dont have any webcaches involved in this case

Comment: If it shows the newer version if you browse from a different computer, then it's probably a client issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with this issue in the past, and ended up writing a httpmodule to deal with it.

It's pretty simple, it just finds all script/css links in head tag (they now need to have runat=server) and appends the assembly version number to the link, in the same way as Tim K describes. This way im sure my clients always fetches the newest css/scripts when my app is updated in production, and never have to deal with this issue again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Internet Service Provider cache, as in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382418/why-can-i-see-my-website-even-though-its-down#382419)?

Answer (score 0):

I was perplexed by this issue then someone said Ctrl+F5. Worked for me :)

Answer (score -1):

When I am developing and I need to be sure that I am seeing changes as I work, I stick the css in the page ie

```
<style type="text/css">
/* your css */
</style>
```

Or you could constantly change the name of the css file itself, not very useful in a production environment, but perhaps okay while developing.

I know it doesn't solve the problem, but for developing it is okay.